# Fade my background change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to change a div bg each 5 seconds.

But I really want to make this transition as a fade effect..

I'm doing this (but I get an abrupt transition instead of a fade one...):

```
<script>
var bgArr = ["images/1.jpg", "images/2.jpg", "images/3.jpg" ]; 
var i=0;
var interval = self.setInterval("changeBg()", 5000)  

function changeBg() {
 if (i>(bgArr.length-1) ) {
  i=0
  $("#header").css("background-image", "url("+bgArr[i]+")");
 }
 else {
  $("#header").css("background-image", "url("+bgArr[i]+")"); 
 } 
 i++;
};


</script>
```

How can I do this transition as a fade... without showing a white space (I mean.. The second image appears slowly over the first one)??

I'm really stuck.. :(

Comment: Can you add a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com) with all your code so we can help you more?

Comment: You need to use two layers on top of each other.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no such thing as background opacity so the images would need to be inside <img> tags or the whole element would have to be faded.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the bgshuffle script. It uses JqueryUI. You will have to include JqueryUI somewhere in your page. The script is posted on github, feel free to extend it if you like:

https://github.com/vikaskumarsingh123/bgshuffle/

**You can simply call it like**:

```
shuffleBG( ['1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg','4.jpg','5.jpg'] );//the array of wallpapers
```

**or Advanced Usage:**

```
shuffleBG(['1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg','4.jpg','5.jpg'], //the array of wallpapers
        '10000', //time between wallpaper change, defaults to 10000ms (10secs)
        '1000', //fade in fade out animation speed, defaults to 1000ms
        'white' //color to fade in and out of, defaults to body backgroundColor or white
);
```

You will usually be calling this function on document.load and it will start changing the background image fade-in-out every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `.fadeTo()`:

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/w13bhcgt/

```
$(function () {
    var bgArr = ['http://png-5.findicons.com/files/icons/1243/hello_kitty/256/flower.png',
        'http://www.vectorimages.org/01/01201101251549265911.png',
        'http://media.janm.org/exhibitions/hellokitty/JANM-HelloKitty-icon-bow.png'];

    var i = 0;

    function Change() {
        $("#header")
            .fadeTo('slow', 1)
            .css("background-image", "url(" + bgArr[i] + ")")
            .fadeTo('slow', 0);
        i++;
        if (i < bgArr.length) setTimeout(Change, 2000);
    }
    Change(0);
});
```

Comment: Almost that!
The problem is that I'm trying to fade without show a blank space!

Something like the image 2 fades over the image 1... And get an infinity loop!

Comment: What's the difference with a `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` then? A steady transition *on the background only* simply isn't possible like this.

Comment: @MarceloBarganha I guess this is the best you can get for the background. you may need to put a div fixed in the background and change the image it contains.